# How to check, what connection urls android phone uses?

Tags: android

I have unrooted Samsung Galaxy S4 (android) and recently started to play/test one of my friends game (not in google store).
Wanted to know, if there is any application/tool/command script, which checks, what urls/server_requests are made throught that game on Windows 7/10.
Like NET tab in Chrome browser in developer tools with all the POST/etc. parameters

Comment: try packet sniffer app

Comment: thanks for answer. Is there particular packet sniffer app, what i need to look for? And do I need to search for this app for PC or phone?

Comment: yes try to check in play store